# Show only 15 days in bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, momentjs, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am just working on Bootstrap datetimepicker plugin, and i need show to only 15 days from current date. how to disable remaining dates?

```
 //only show 15 days
   $('#dp').datetimepicker({
// to disable all previous days from current day 
      minDate: moment().add(1)         
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its works

```
//only show 15 days
   $('#dp3').datetimepicker({
      minDate: moment().add(1),
      maxDate: moment().add(15,'days')
  });
```